# Java: How keep running process in thread and read it's values?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety

I don't know if this is the best approach so that's why I'm asking your help guys.

This is my problem, I'm developing an app where you have the 'read' button, when the user hit this button then the program start to read some values and save this values in my database, okay ?

So I think when the user hit 'read' I start a thread, that's because the user can do another thing if he wants without the app been freeze.
But I cannot access the values read by this thread.

There's another way to do that ?

EDIT:

```
    private void jtb_readerItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
        // getting some values provided by the user       

        if (buttonReaderState()){
            if (supervisory == null)
                supervisory = new Supervisory(ip, broadcast, deviceID);
                supervisory.start();
        }
    }                                           

// Supervisory class
    public void start(){
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        Thread t = new Thread(scan);
        t.start();
        threadState = true;
    }

    class Scan extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            // inside the tread I have to initiate another 'supervisory' object, is that right ? 
            Supervisory s = new Supervisory(ip, broadcast, deviceID);
            while (threadState){
                try {
                    s.active();

                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void active() throws IOException, Exception  {
        // getting this values from my hardware like temperature and anothers things.

        for (int i = 0; i < ois.size(); i++) {
            ObjectIdentifier oi = ois.get(i);

            //analog input
            if (i == 1)
                aI = Float.parseFloat(getPresentValue(localDevice, oi));
            //analog output
            if (i == 2)
                aO = Float.parseFloat(getPresentValue(localDevice, oi));
            //binary input
            if (i == 3)
                bI = getBinaryValue(getPresentValue(localDevice, oi));
            //binary output
            if (i == 4)
                bO = getBinaryValue(getPresentValue(localDevice, oi));
        }

    }
```

After reading this values I would like to show this values in the interface that I'm building, but it seems that I cannot have access to these values (aI,aO,bI,bO).

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "cannot access the values read by this thread"?

Comment: @m0skit0 I update my post, I hope that I be more clear now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a reference to the interface you have. E.g. you can add a `JFrame owner` field to Supervisory class and pass your values there.